# How to display bin folder of android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse Helios. my problem is i can't see bin folder  in my project in eclipse. actually it is there in project where my project is physically located(in workspace).
any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option of "show view" in the bottom left corner of eclipse, from there find/select the navigator look of to show the folder, this will show you the **bin** folder. See the image
[image]