# Duplication of resource folders within an Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am writing an Eclipse Plug-in which requires me to add two new configurations to the ManagedProject upon mouse-click on a menu option. I basically runs on Android projects that has Native Support Added to it. I am trying to achieve this using ManagedBuildManager and Configuration classes from the CDT core plug-in interfaces.(org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.* package).

To complete the task, I create two new Configurations for the project and run the exportArtifactInfo() method to complete the action. In the end, the configuration gets added but the project folder contains duplicate folders of all the original folders in the Project folder.

I looked up if there is a bug in CDT 4.0 and found that it is indeed a resolved bug.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194395

But I cannot figure out what the actual fix is for this bug. If anyone has encountered and fixed it or knows how to fix this, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: That bug was marked resolved in 2007 for CDT 4.0.1, current CDT release is 8.2

Comment: Yup.. Currently, I am working with CDT 8.2. This is the closest thing I could find related to the problem I am having.

Comment: The following question relates to the outcome of creating a project using my plugin. The solution provided is to change the view from Project Explorer to Navigator. But I would like to know if this problem can be prevented/fixed altogether. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437227/how-to-hide-src-folder-from-eclipse-project-explorer