# How to remove file system folders from eclipse package explorer view?

Tags: eclipse, ide

In the "package explorer view" of eclipse, some of my "file system folders" (e.g. `src/main`) are shown (my source folder is set to `src/main/java`).

[image]

Showing the folder twice is redundant. How can I prevent this behaviour by default?

Comment: You should rather use Navigator View or Filters. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437227/how-to-hide-src-folder-from-eclipse-project-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1) Right click on the project, choose Properties.

2) Java Build Path

3) Source tab, select the folder on your build path (src/main) then select Excluded node

4) Click Edit... button and add the pattern to exclude (src/main) and include (src/main/java) from the build path. You can fine-tune it with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a C project.

On the top-right angle of the project explorer, you can find a triangle icon. Click on that, you will find one of these two following menu items (depending on the version):

1. "Customize Window"
2. "Filters"

Click the one you find, and you will get a checkboxes list with "Non Java-Elements" option. Toggle it and it works.

In case of C/C++ project, the entry is called  "Non C-Objects".

Tried on Eclipse Oxygen and MCUxpresso.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple.

1. click the project of your choice.
2. Hit the 'edit' bottom.
3. scroll down to the 'delete'.