# Double source folder in eclipse when creating new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse kepler to make a maven 2 or 3 project. I used the "webapp" archetype to start with a clean empty project, and I followed some simple helloworld tutorials. However, I noticed that in eclipse my src folder is shown twice, as seen in the picture below:

[image]

This is very undesirable, it takes up additional space and they are not very well synchronized, for example the src on the bottom contains the `"webapp"` folder, but the src on top doesn't. What's the deal with this double structure? Colleagues of me, who use an older version of eclipse, don't see the `"java resources"` subtab but I can't find a way to turn it off.

Comment: Try package explorer instead of project explorer. It should still show both src folders, but in a nicer way.

Comment: That's because there are folders below your `src` folder that are not source folders, like `webapp`. Where should that folder be shown otherwise? About the `Java Resources` group, that seems to be specific to the "webapp" archetype.

Comment: @atamanroman thanks, that view is indeed better for me because it doesn't show duplicate files or spurious metadata!

Comment: @user1884155 Glad that I could help. Please accept my answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try package explorer instead of project explorer. It should still show both src folders, but in a nicer way.

Comment: Is this the right answer  ? I know it has been accepted, but i read elsewhere that package explorer view will be deprecated shortly.

Comment: This answer is about 2 years old. Things may have changed.

Answer (score 5):

[Anderas B. posted a fix on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289959/4020859):

Click the dropdown arrow in the upper right corner of the Package Explorer, then "Filters..." and then check "Name filter patterns" and write "src". Then the second src folder is hidden.

__

Works only for maven projects, otherwise all src folders are hidden.