# Suppress display of 'src' folder in Eclipse's Package and Project Explorer views

Tags: eclipse, maven, view, directory

If I have a Maven project in Eclipse there are the folders of the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in the Explorer views:

- [image: folder] src/main/java
- [image: folder] src/main/resources
- [image: folder] src/test/java
- [image: folder] src/test/resources

but also a:

- [image: folder] src

  - [image: folder] main
  - [image: folder] test

with *main* and *test* being the only sub-folders.

Is it possible to get rid off the display of this *src* folder in the Explorer views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide src folder from eclipse project explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14437227/2985643) (though I don't see the solutions offered as being satisfactory).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide src folder from eclipse project explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437227/how-to-hide-src-folder-from-eclipse-project-explorer)